# Single Table Inheritance with Polymorthic using child class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, sti

I have the following setup where the class MediaItem has STI and ContentView is polymorphic

```
class MediaItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_views, as: :media
end

class Video < MediaItem
end

class Track < MediaItem
end

class ContentView < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :media, polymorphic: true
end
```

In this situation when doing actions like Video.first.content_views.create the column media_type is set as the child class 'Video' rather than 'MediaItem'

This becomes a problem when trying to write queries like so

```
ContentView.where(media_type: 'Video' )
```

How I can tell Rails to use the child class rather than than the base_class?

My current non-ideal solution is writing this:

```
class Video < MediaItem
  has_many :content_views, ->{ where(media_type: 'Video') }, as: :media, dependent: :destroy
  scope :join_content_views, -> { joins("INNER JOIN \"content_views\" ON \"content_views\".\"media_id\" = \"media_items\".\"id\" AND \"content_views\".\"media_type\" = 'Video'")}
end
```

and having to manually write:

```
video.content_views.create(media_type: 'Video', media_id: video.id)
```

This sets the media_type correctly as 'Video' and allows for the queries:

```
Video.joins_content_views
```

and

```
video.content_views
```

Does anyone know of a better way to handle this in Rails?

Comment: Why are you using polymorphic references here if you're only referencing items stored in one table? Polymorphic refs are for tackling models that can possibly have same `id`s, so they are given an explicit type. Here type can be derived from a fetched entry and `id` collisions within one table are not possible.

Comment: Many other tables use ContentViews, but for simplicity I've only mentioned those related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, I'd setup subclassed has_many relationships using class_name:

```
class MediaItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_views, as: :media, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :video_content_views, ->{ where(media_type: 'Video') }, class_name: 'Video', as: :media 
end
```

You should also just use `type` for the column or tell Rails which column to use for STI, so you can automatically hint content_views classes.

Comment: The MediaItem table doesn't have a column 'media_type' - that column is in the ContentView table. MediaItem which has STI has the column 'type' already.
This means the has_many :video_content_views doesn't make any sense in relation to content views